# What are these pointy things along the taxiway?

Tags: airport

I've noticed these blue cylinder based objects in and around the vicinity of the taxiways.

[image: photo with objects of interest circled]

I know this isn't probable but If an aircraft knocks into one of these, will it have resilience or will it shatter?

Answer (score 26):

As @tedder42 pointed out in a comment, those are **taxiway lighting fixtures**. Ideally, if an aircraft impacts a lighting fixture it will *neither* have resilience nor will it shatter. Instead it should be **frangible**; there should be a deliberately weak section which will break away cleanly upon impact, preventing significant damage to the aircraft. This is true for all objects and structures within taxiway and runway safety areas.

The relevant [faa-regulations](/questions/tagged/faa-regulations) are Advisory Circulars [150/5220-23, Frangible Connections](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1039499), and [150/5345-46, Specification for Runway and Taxiway Light Fixtures](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/150_5345-46). AC 150/5220-23 "does not constitute a regulation and is not legally binding in its own right." However, AC 150/5345-46 "is mandatory for lighting or projects funded under the Airport Improvement Program (AIP) with revenue from the Passenger Facility Charges (PFC) program."

AC 150/5345-46 includes the following requirement:

> **3.4.2.1 Yield Device**
>
> **a.** Each elevated light fixture must have a yield point near the point or position where it attaches to the base plate or mounting stake.
>
> 1. The yield point must be no more than 1.5 inches (38 mm) above the threaded interface of the elevated light cover (see AC 150/5345-42 for more information). See AC 150/5340-30 for additional information about light fixture yield point above grade location.
> 2. The yield point must give way before any other part of the fixture is damaged, and must withstand a bending moment of 150 foot-pounds (203 Newton-meters (N-m) without failure.
> 3. The yield point must cleanly separate from the mounting system before the bending moment reaches 500 foot-pounds (678 N-m).
>
> [snip]
>
> **b.** Type L-860 light fixtures may bend instead of separating. The fixture must not sway more than 1 inch from vertical under the specified wind loading.

More information and possible exceptions to the above requirements may be found in the linked documents.

Comment: Hopefully most professional pilots are competent enough to avoid hitting these things too often though?  Might not damage the aircraft, but if they keep having to shut down the taxiways in order to repair these things, that'd have a significant impact beyond the simple cost of replacement.

Comment: Hopefully pilots aren't running off the edges of runways and taxiways every day. But the standard is designed for the day when "hopefully" fails.

Answer (score 9):

There are standards for everything. In this case, you're talking about the L-861T taxiway edge light.

[AC 150/5345-46D "Specification for Runway and Taxiway Light Fixtures"](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/150-5345-46d/150_5345_46d.pdf) describes how the lights should break away ("yield device"):

> Each elevated light fixture must have a yield point near the point or position where the light attaches to the base plate or mounting stake.  The yield point must be no more than 1-1/2 inches (38.10 mm) above grade, must give way before any other part of the fixture is damaged, and must withstand a bending moment of 150 foot-pounds (203 Newton-meters (N-m) without failure.

There's no requirement they the lenses be anti-shatter. In fact using glass or plastic is allowed, the only discussion is about verifying the light output.

It also specifies the brightness, visibility angles, and maximum height (14 inches, except for snow banks).